# Unable to Install Sipp in solaris sparc 5.10

Tags: solaris, sparc

I am trying to install SIPp on solaris sparc 5.10. when I am firing a "make"
command, it is giving me an error.
 lake42.rice.iit.edu]/> make
make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 22: Unexpected end of line seen
I am stuck at this point and not getting any help in web. Can you please help me
out so that I can move ahead in installing SIPp.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need GNU make, and not the traditional BSD make shipped with Solaris.

Try invoking 'gmake' instead -- it might be installed in `/usr/sfw/bin/gmake`.

Comment: I am trying "gmake" to compile the Sipp but getting following error.
[unknown]/> gmake
make OSNAME=`uname|sed -e "s/CYGWIN.*/CYGWIN/"` MODELNAME=`uname -m|sed "s/Power Macintosh/ppc/"` sipp
make: Fatal error in reader: Makefile, line 22: Unexpected end of line seen
Current working directory /opt/software/sipp-3.0.src
gmake: *** [all] Error 1

I have installed both the libraries libpcap-0.9.5 and libnet-1.1.2.1. Please need some suggestion regarding this issue.

Comment: Obvious follow up question: what's in line 22? Otherwise you'll have to provide more exact pointers to what you are installing so that someone might check the actual instructions in the source archive.

Answer (score 0):

Try remove the "include" line in the file